# При заливке на плей маркет выдало сообщение о проблеме с 64х битной версией

Tags: android, unity3d

> Этот выпуск не соответствует требованиям Google Play к 64-разрядным
>   приложениям
>
> Следующие файлы APK или наборы App Bundle доступны для 64-разрядных
>   устройств, но содержат только 32-разрядный нативный код: 28.
>
> С 1 февраля 2020 г. все выпуски должны соответствовать требованиям
>   Google Play к 64-разрядному коду.
>
> Включите в приложение 64-разрядный и 32-разрядный нативный код.
>   Используйте формат публикации "Набор Android App Bundle", чтобы каждое
>   устройство скачивало только соответствующий его архитектуре нативный
>   код. Это поможет уменьшить общий размер приложени

Собираю игру Unity. Использую app bundle.  Собираю как под 32х разрядные так и под 64х Все было окей после августа когда нужно было обязательно добавлять 64х битные версии. А что может быть не так в это раз ?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно собирать билд на бэкенде IL2CPP с галочками ARMv7 и ARM64, с Target API Level 28 и галочкой Build App Bundle в окне сборки. Если всё стоит правильно, то проблем никаких быть не должно.

Comment: у меня все так же, только в настройках target api level  стоит Automatic

Comment: @Andrey, попробуйте выбрать вручную, возможно, у вас старый SDK и ему чего-то не хватает. Для выбора API 28 всё равно будет доступен, но если он старый - Unity предложит обновить.